# Why not incrementing z?

Tags: c, matrix, while-loop

I am trying to write a simple state machine executor in C. I have this code:

```
while(1) {  
  strcpy(fsm.state[x][z], lines[i]);
  printf("%i %i\n", x, z);
  z++; i++;
  if(strcmp(lines[i], ".") == 0) x++; z = 0;
  if(strcmp(lines[i], "") == 0) break;
}
```

I don't understand why if *z* should only be reset when the current line I am reading from the *lines* array is equal to ".", which happens every third occurrence in my test scenario, that *z* stays equal to 0, even when *x* is successfully incremented every third line.

I need output like so:

> 1 0 \n 1 1 \n 1 2 \n 2 0 \n 2 1 \n 2 2 \n 3 0 \n 3 1 , etc...

Instead I get:

> 1 0 \n 1 0 \n 1 0 \n 2 0 \n 2 0 \n 2 0 \n 3 0 \n 3 0, etc...

What do I have to change? This might be a stupid question, but I really don't understand what's wrong here.

Thank you kindly for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

z is always being set to zero. The if statement doesn't work based on the line, it goes to the next semi-colon.

```
if(strcmp(lines[i], ".") == 0) x++; z = 0;
if(strcmp(lines[i], "") == 0) break;
```

Is the same as:

```
if(strcmp(lines[i], ".") == 0){
 x++;
}

z = 0;

if(strcmp(lines[i], "") == 0){
 break;
}
```

Since you have two statements (`x++; z = 0;`), you need to put braces around them to specify the condition:

```
if(strcmp(lines[i], ".") == 0){
 x++;
 z = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

use braces, avoids confusion :)

```
while(1) {  
  strcpy(fsm.state[x][z], lines[i]);
  printf("%i %i\n", x, z);
  z++; i++;
  if(strcmp(lines[i], ".") == 0) {
        x++; 
        z = 0;
  }
  if(strcmp(lines[i], "") == 0) {
        break;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 It's worth noting that when not using braces, only the first statement is conditionally executed, i.e. up to the semicolon, not the line break.

Comment: or, in this case, you can put a `,` instead of `;` ;)

Comment: Thanks, so it was just because I didn't use braces. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(strcmp(lines[i], ".") == 0) x++; z = 0;
```

is the same as:

```
if(strcmp(lines[i], ".") == 0) 
   x++; 
z = 0;
```

You probably want

```
if(strcmp(lines[i], ".") == 0) {
     x++; 
     z = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this line:

```
if(strcmp(lines[i], ".") == 0) x++; z = 0;
```

Without braces, if will only include the statement `x++` and your compiler will interpret your code such like:

```
if(strcmp(lines[i], ".") == 0)
    x++;
z = 0;
```

Whereas `z = 0` is executed everytime. To fix that, use braces (for 2 or more statements in an if block)

```
if(strcmp(lines[i], ".") == 0) {
    x++;
    z = 0;
}
```